# Combine Two or more named ranges (with formulas) to one named range (array)

Tags: excel, powerpivot, cube, named-ranges, datamodel

I am trying to use formula.1 to get data from the Data model and I have managed to use O7:P7 as an array in the Cubermember function.

like this:

This is sample data.
=CUBEVALUE("ThisWorkbookDataModel",CUBEMEMBER("ThisWorkbookDataModel",**{"[Table1].[A1].&[A]","[Table1].[A2].&[D]"}**),CUBEMEMBER("ThisWorkbookDataModel","[Measures].[Sum of A3]"))

O7 = "[Table1].[A1].&[A]"

P7 = "[Table1].[A2].&[D]"

formula.1 =CUBEVALUE("ThisWorkbookDataModel",CUBEMEMBER("ThisWorkbookDataModel",**O7:P7**),CUBEMEMBER("ThisWorkbookDataModel","[Measures].[Sum of A3]"))

This works, But I want to make the array dynamic with named ranges for both variables.

like this:

NamedRange1: ="[Table1].["&A2&"].&["&A1&"]"

NamedRange2: ="[Table1].["&B2&"].&["&B1&"]"

CombinedRange: must be an array with (NamedRange1 and NamedRange2)

I hope I have explained what I want.

I anyone can help that would be grand :)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCnQl.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `CHOOSE`:

`=CUBEVALUE("ThisWorkbookDataModel",CUBEMEMBER("ThisWorkbookDataModel",CHOOSE({1,2},NamedRange1,NamedRange2)),CUBEMEMBER("ThisWorkbookDataModel","[Measures].[Sum of A3]"))`

Comment: Hi Jos, is there a way to make this array dynamic? 
Like:
instead of {1,2}, can it be if {1,2,3...} and if there are only two values available it works for only two. If there is 3 values then for 3...

IT'S NOT FOR THE CUBE FUNCTION NOW.

I need this to be dynamic for an Average({1,2...},(Name1,Name2...) formula.

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: Hi Rafi. What version of Excel do you have?

Comment: Excel LTSC Pro Plus 2021, Version 2108

Comment: I have used combination of text join and sequence to solve this. Thanks =TEXTJOIN(SEQUENCE(